# A probably very simple question about absolutely continuous measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have managed to become confused in trying to definitively pin down the definition of absolute continuity of measures. Different sources seem to quote different statements (some seem to be about positive measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, some about the total variation $|\mu|, |\nu|$ of unsigned measures) and I was wondering if someone could definitively clarify the definition for me, and perhaps address if there's a meaningful distinction between the case of positive measures and unsigned measures. (I ask this last part because I'm aware that positive measures aren't necessarily bounded but at least one of the components $\mu ^+$, $\mu^-$ of a signed measure $\mu$ must be.)